# Why my Tikz picture doesn't rotate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

Here is my code in `Tikz`format picture and I made many changes to rotate it, include using some package and changing in angle values but it still doesn't rotate, I don't know what's the problem.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{45}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{20}{30}{90}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis on top,
        xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
        view/h=110,
        title={\tiny $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, Rotate Please},
        ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            z buffer=sort,
            mesh/interior colormap={purplegreen}{color=(purple) color=(green)},
            colormap={periodic}{%
            color=(blue) 
            color=(yellow) 
            color=(orange) 
            color=(red)
            color=(orange) 
            color=(yellow) 
            color=(blue)},
            domain=-2:2, domain y=0:360,
            samples=20, samples y=20,
            variable=\u, variable y=\v,
        point meta=u,
        ]
        ({2 * cos(v)},{3 * sin(v)},{u});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also I don't want the numbers appear on axis', what should I make changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using pgfplots! Use `view={20}{45}` instead! (NO, you cannot use tikz-3dplot's rotation command to rotate pgfplots's plot. They are simply indepedent.)

Comment: Instead of 'view/h=110' ?

Comment: Oops I mislooked that. So you did set the `view`. Then what you do want to achieve? which part of the picture should be rotated?

Comment: I want to rotate whole of picture include cylinder and axis'.

Comment: Then that is fairly impossible. The `axis` draws everything on the 2D plane!

Comment: off-topic: in your MWE(i) with `standalone` you can't use `figure` environment, (ii) instead `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` in real document use just `\centering`, (iii) MWE has hidden characters, (iv)  some `tikz` libraries are missing ....

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. I will change (i)-(iii) but what do change for (iv).

Comment: for (iv)  i receives error "tikz/surf" not defined. I suppose, that some `tikz` library is missing, but now all works!

Comment: I don't understand how you like to rotate. If you add `rotate=<angle>` to `tikzpicture` options, that the whole image will rotate for `<angle>`.

Comment: I didn't know. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: @Zarko This is planar rotation and is different with spatial rotation which done about a 3D-pint. This command `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords` means what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us sit down and see what are the options:

First of all, **NO**, you cannot use `\tdplotxxx` to rotate `axis`. The former is from `tikz-3dplot` and the latter is from `pgfplots`. They are basically working independently. (off topic: I used to think `tikz-3dplot`>`pgfplots`; But now I know `pgfplots`>>`tikz-3dplot`.)

The following uses only `pgfplots`

- If you want to rotate just the data points, not axis, then there is a phase in `pgfplots` that allows you to modify data points. Search `filter points` in the manual.
- If you want to rotate the data points together with axis, then you can use `view={12}{34}` together with `rotate=56` (the 2D rotation). The combination of these two should give you all possible 3D rotations.
- If you want to rotate just the axis, combine the previous two methods.

If you want to stick to `tikz-3dplot`, then you have to give up `axis`.

Comment: I could't find `filter points` in my manual file: **Tantau Till, TikZ and pgf, Manual for version 3.0.1a (2013)**. The combine `view={12}{34}` with `rotate=56`  gives me something as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @MyGlasses I mean [the manual of pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). Sometimes I mistakenly assume that I am clear.

Comment: I don't want the numbers appear on axis', what should I make changes in my file, please.

Comment: Something like `xticklabel={}`.