# Possible to rotate using addplot3?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to rotate a circular quadrant about a diagonal in the xy-plane. I tried using the following code using `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords` to no avail. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,external}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,plotmarks}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{150}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 8cm,
    height = 8cm,
    view/h=25,
    axis lines=none
]

      \draw [->,black] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:20,0,0);
      \draw [->,black] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:0,0,20);
      \draw [->,black] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:0,-20,0);  

      \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{20}{20}{0}%     

      \addplot3[tdplot_rotated_coords, surf, opacity = 0.1, fill 
      opacity = 0.5,
      samples=16,domain=0:15.0,
      y domain=-0.5*pi:0,z buffer=sort,color=gray!60!white]
      (x, {sqrt( 15*15-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))}, 0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `axis` environment use a different coordinate system? Does it work *without* rotation?

Comment: Did you bother reading the console output when you compiled? It tries to help you. I don't think it will make this work, but if you can make it work, it is giving you the clues as to how.

Comment: @cfr - If you mean can I run the above code with the `tdplot_rotated_coords`, then yes it does. I did read the console output if that was concerning you - it simply warns that the z-axis is of infinite thickness - it has no discernible range of values. It shouldn't, I have a flat surface in the xy-plane.

Comment: I meant the warnings about the `compat` level as well. But, as I say, you're trying to mix different coordinate systems as far as I can tell. `axis cs` is not the standard coordinate system.

Comment: I set it to compat 1.9, if I change it to 1.14, the code fails to run.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365824/

Comment: Any updates? Does the link solved(or helped to solve) your problem?